# MS Graph - SharePoint Error: Not adding member

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am calling the Graph API to do the following (directly one after the other),

1. Create a new User in M365 (e.g. myNewUser)
2. Add the User to an existing MS Team
3. Create a Privte Channel (e.g. myPrivateChannel)
4. Add the User to the Private Channel
   The user gets created, added to the team, channel etc., But the user was **unable to access the files in the Private Channel**. After some investigation I found that the user had not been added to the "Members" Group in the corresponding SharePoint Group. I manually added the user and it worked.
   Also if I the break the steps and give a good gap between the user creation in M365 and adding the user to the Private Channel, it works.
   But in my situation, I have to do it all at once. That does not work. Looks like there is some issue with this. Any idea what?

Comment: You tried Microsoft Graph API to perform all the above actions or through portal?

Comment: @Dev Though the Graph API

Comment: Cool. I want to have a look at the step # 4s payload that you're using... so please share

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/908686-bug-reports/suggestions/39135010-private-channel-members-cannot-access-files), there is a lengthy delay current with membership sync.

During the creation of the private channel, the members are not always added to the members' group of the site collection. It's probably causing the weirdness. It's probably causing the weirdness.

Owners probably get added directly to site collection admin of that site collection so it's quicker than members being synced to the SharePoint group itself.

You may have a try below methods:

- A workaround is to remove and re-add the members to the private channel within Teams.
- Use SharePoint Rest API to check site groups
- You can add the user during the [channel creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1):

[image]

BR

Comment: thanks for the clarification and workaround. I'll try them. Meanwhile, could you please raise an issue with the Eng team to fix this. We are in the EDU space and have to reguarly create private teams & add, reamove 100s of users. Thanks.

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE: This is a serious problem as this is not happening only to newly added users but also for users who are already in the system. Not all members of a "Private" channel are added as "Members" to the corresponding Sharepont Goup and therefore they are uanble to access the files. Please raise an issue with the ENG teams ASAP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, Have you been able to raise am issue with the Eng Team. This is still not working.

Comment: I tried all the workarounds even adding the user to the channel while it is created but it doesn't help. This is a Bug that MS has to fix. Could you please raise an issue for this. Thanks.

Comment: Raised a bug, will get back to you soon.